# How to install squashfs-tools on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I tried running `unsquashfs and got:

```
$ unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs
The program 'unsquashfs' is currently not installed, You can install it by typing:
```

So I went to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools
E: Unable to locate package  squashfs-tools
```

How do I install `squashfs-tools` on Ubuntu?

Comment: Please don't cross post. Among other reasons so that this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 15):

update your repository first, and then install your package

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools
```

Comment: It works also for Centos!

Answer (score 0):

This workd for CentOS 7:

```
sudo yum update && sudo yum install squashfs-tools
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Open terminal type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools
```

and you're done with that.